# Term for hyperbol-ish?

Tags: terminology, area

Let $f$ be a function on a subset of the unit interval, such that for all $x$ in its domain the area in the unit square above $( x, f( x ) )$ is constant,
$$
    \int_x^1 \left( 1 - f\left( x \right) \right) dy = \left( 1 - f\left( x \right) \right) \left( 1 - x \right) = A.
$$
Then $f$ is a hyperbolic curve.

Now, consider the following related question. Given a strictly decreasing function $h$ on the unit interval, let $f$ be such that for all $x$, the area above the point $( x, f( x ) )$ and under $h$ is constant,
$$
    \int_x^1 \left( h\left( y \right) - f\left( x \right) \right)_+ dy = A.
$$
Is there a standard term for the "type" of function $f$ is?

Comment: Your question doesn't make much sense.  What is the "(for all $x$ ...) area above $(x,f(x))$ in the unit square"?  There is no "area" above $(x,f(x))$ for any fixed $x$, only a line segment $(f(x),1]$.

Comment: @user10354138 I hoped the integral would clarify: the area in the rectangle with lower-left point $( x, f( x ) )$ and upper-right point $( 1, 1 )$. Happy to update if the rewording helps anyone but I find the shorter expression clearer.